# Pages build and deployment workflow run cancelled from main branch

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I keep getting notifications that Pages build and deployment workflow run cancelled from main branch. I could view my work [here](https://eevontually.github.io/build-a-markdown-previewer/) so I don't know what the messages actually mean.
[actions](https://github.com/eevontually/build-a-markdown-previewer/actions/runs/4659252408)

I am not sure if what I'm doing is right because I could view my github page but I still keep getting the notifications. I am noob so I don't really know what branches and fork are for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to view your project at the expected URL, then it's likely that the GitHub Action completed successfully despite the cancellation message.

Regarding your question about branches and forks, branches are used to work on different versions of a project simultaneously. For example, you may create a new branch to work on a new feature while keeping the main branch stable. A fork, on the other hand, is a copy of a repository that you create in your own GitHub account. You would typically create a fork of a repository if you want to make changes to the code without affecting the original repository.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. Your explanations on the branches and fork are very clear. I will definitely use them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're deploying using the built-in workflow for pages. That workflow uses concurrency controls, so if you make a push that triggers the workflow before the previous run has finished, the previous run gets cancelled; see the message on the [cancelled workflow](https://github.com/eevontually/build-a-markdown-previewer/actions/runs/4659252408):

> Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'pages build and deployment @ main' exists

Comment: Ok. It may be because I was trying different solutions when I was not able to view my project. How can I improve so that this does not happen again in the future?

Comment: @jeevs As long as you use the pre-made workflow, you can't really change that behaviour, but it really just occurs when you push twice within the duration of that workflow, which is less than one minute.